# Are statements after END in stored procedure executed?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Are statements after END in stored procedure executed?

I found that a stored procedure of mine includes a drop procedure after the BEGIN/END block. However, every time I execute the stored procedure elsewhere in code it seems to work fine and the 
pvd_sp_yyy is not dropped. I am not sure why? I am worried about this in the first place and so I am going to remove the additional statement regardless.

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Thanks

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pvd_xxx]
    @var
AS

BEGIN

    DECLARE @RETURN int

    SET @RETURN = 0

    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM table1
        WHERE name = @var
    )
    BEGIN
        SET @RETURN = 1
    END

    RETURN @RETURN

END


IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[pvd_sp_yyy]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
    DROP PROCEDURE [pvd_sp_yyy]
```

Comment: I don't want to the include the drop procedure statement. This is a mistake so I will remove it. 1. I would like to clarify though if it would be executed at all. Others seem to indicate it might?? 2. Also, to prevent me making the same mistake, should I always include a GO after the END?

Comment: I'm intrigued - did you ever find out why the second proc wasn't being dropped? (the way your code is written, the `IF EXISTS ... DROP ...`  code WOULD definitely be called on every execution...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BEGIN/END are not the limits of a stored procedure. The end of batch (GO usually) is.

So, yes, code is executed.

This also means the BEGIN/END are unnecessary... like parenthesis around parameters. This is SQL: not a high level client language.

I've quite often left a GRANT EXECUTE inside the stored proc... :)

Comment: I don't want to the include the drop procedure statement. This is a mistake so I will remove it. 1. I would like to clarify though if it would be executed at all. You seem to indicate it might?? 2. Also, to prevent me making the same mistake, should I always include a GO after the END?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as all you have declared is a code block. The procedure contents do not end until you put a GO to execute the batch.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want the `DROP PROCEDURE` to be executed then it needs to be the only statement in a batch, so separate your `ALTER PROCEDURE` and `DROP PROCEDURE` with a `GO`.